# If T has a basis of Eigen Vector, how do I know that T can be represented as diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In Linear algebra, suppose I have:

- A linear transformation $T:V\to V$
- A basis of eigen vectors $(v_1,...,v_n)$

How do I conclude that $T$ can be represented with a diagonal matrix $D$ ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How does the matrix of $T$ in the basis $(v_1,\,\ldots,\, v_n)$ look?

Comment: I'm not sure it may have different forms, why must it be diagonal?

Comment: is the dimension of $V$ , $n$ ?

Comment: yes it us of dimension n should I edit it?

Comment: @vondip , wouldn't be bad.

Comment: No @vondip, the matrix of $\,T\,$ wrt the basis of eigenvectors $\,\{v_1,...,v_n\}\,$  cannot have but one unique, single form: diagonal. Do it!

Comment: do what? How can I test this?

Comment: @vondip: do you know how to associate a matrix to a linear tansformation with a choice of a basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the comments under the question I think a more comprehensive answer might be helpful.

**Bases**

A set $  \{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n\}\subset V$ is said to be a basis of $  V$ if every vector $  v\in V$ has a unique representation as

$$  \sum_{i=1}^na_ie_i $$

It can be shown that this condition is equivalent to the basis being a linearly independent, spanning set. A set $  \{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ is said to be linearly independent if the only linear combination of the $  v_i$ is the trivial one; i.e. linear independence is

$$  \sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i=\mathbf{0}\,\Rightarrow\,a_i=0\,,\forall\,i=1,\dots,n$$

In turn this is equivalent to the condition that none of the vectors are a linear combination of the others --- in some sense the 'directions' of the vectors are all different. A spanning set is one in which all possible linear combinations exhaust the space:

$$  \text{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}:=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i :a_i\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$

i.e. a set $  A$ is a spanning set for $  V$ if span $  A=V$. The dimension of a vector space is given by the number of vectors in a basis.

**Linear Maps**

One of the first things to do when an abstract structure is defined --- for example a vector space --- is to consider functions between them. A linear map is a function between two vector spaces that preserves the operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication. In other words a linear map is any function $  T:V\rightarrow U$ where $  T(u+_V\lambda v)=T(u)+_U\lambda T(v)$ for any vectors $  u,v\in V$ and scalar $  \lambda\in \mathbb{F}_V$. The quick calculation:

$$  T\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_ie_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^na_iT(e_i)$$

shows that a linear map is defined by what it does to the basis vectors. Let $  \{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ and $  \{f_1,\dots,f_m\}$ be bases for $  U$ and $  V$. If the linear map is defined by the equations:

$$  T(e_i)=\sum_{j=1}^mb^i_jf_j\,,\,\,\,i=1,\dots,n$$

then the matrix $  A$ with columns $  c_i=(b^i_1\,b^i_2\,\cdots\,b^i_m)^T$ acts on the vectors $  e_1=(1\,0\,\cdots\,0)^T,\,e_2=(0\,1\,0\,\cdots\,0),\cdots, e_n=(0\,\cdots\,0\,1)$ according to $  T$. Hence, once a basis is fixed, a linear map is nothing but a matrix (and indeed a matrix is suitably linear).

**Answer to your question**

Now if your basis is comprised of eigenvectors $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ then what your linear map $T:V\rightarrow V$  does to the basis vectors is

$$T v_i=\lambda_i v_i.$$

Hence by the arguments in the previous section, the matrix of $T$, say $A$ just has the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Given a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$, the $i$th column of the matrix $A$ in this basis is $Av_i$, written in terms of $\mathcal{B}$. If $Av_i = \lambda_i v_i$, then the $i$th column has $\lambda_i$ in the $i$th row, and zero everywhere else. Thus the matrix only has entries on the diagonal.